# How to know what elisp files are read (I need this for debugging purpose)?

Tags: elisp

Let's say I need to check if hello.el file is read or not.

```
(defun hello ()
  "Test"
  (interactive)
  (message "Hello, world"))

(format "hello")
(provide 'smcho)
```

I used the (format "hello") to show something, but it doesn't seem to work. 
How can I know if an elisp module is read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `message` instead:

```
(message "hello")
```

[`format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Formatting-Strings.html) simply generates a formatted string, much like if you had

```
(+ 1 2)
```

which would result in adding two numbers.  Nothing is done with the result, which is why you didn't see it.  If you're familiar with C, it's much like having a line

```
sprintf(s, "hello");   /* this produces no output */
```

*Note:* If you have lots of these, you might need to customize the variable [`message-log-max`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Logging-Messages.html).